# Primefaces selectors not updating a panelGroup

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selector

I am trying Primefaces selectors and it appears that it couldn't update an `panelGroup`.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="updateMe">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="submit">
        <p:ajax process="@form" update="@(.updateMe)" oncomplete="alert(1)"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

In this case the `panelGroup` never gets updated. But if I change the `panelGroup` to `<p:outputPanel>`, then it worked fine.

Observing the generated HTML, the only difference is that the `<span>` generated by `panelGroup` doesn't have an `id` while the one generated by `outputPanel` has an `id`. Could this be the reason why the first one is not getting updated (cos jQuery selector couldn't find the component id?)

If that is the case, is there any other component that does not have any ids and should be avoided when using Primefaces selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Primefaces selector jQuery is used to select components on client side, and discover their client ids. When AJAX is sent one of parameters that is sent is `javax.faces.partial.render` whose value are client ids of components which should be updated. If component doesn't have client id it can't be updated directly, you can update parent component for example. Provide id attribute for `panelGroup` and try to update it with Primefaces selector.

Comment: Thanks! I added id attribute for `panelGroup` and it was working. But I think I would probably just stay with `p:outputPanel`, it saves me the headache to come up with meaningful names for the ids..
Again, thanks for the explanation!